# How can you properly use SVN when developing a webapplication for Windows and Linux/Unix?

Tags: svn, version-control

We are currently developing a web application meant to run in Linux/Unix web server and Windows web servers. Our app for both systems are very similar, being a external library (wkHTMLtoPDF) and its wrapper the only real difference between them.

So we wish to maintain a set of common files, which will be actively under development, while the OS specific libraries are kept apart. This is specially relevant since some of our developers work in linux, others in Windows and some other in MAC.

Up until now we've been locking those libraries and wrappers from committing but sometimes someone forgets and, well, it gets messy.

To address this problem, I thought of creating different repositories:

1. Common
2. UNIX 32
3. UNIX 64
4. Windows

When someone checks out, they choose a version which will download Common + the selected OS. Files should be in the same folder but any changes to those files would be committed to their respective repository.

Is this possible?

NOTE: Those files would not actually be in the same folder since wkhtmltopdf will live in myapp/libraries/wkhtmltopdf while the rest is at myapp/

Comment: Why not use git? It's easier to create sub repositories referenced by the main repository. They are not downloaded when a you clone the main repository and you can create a script to clone the appropriate sub repositories dependeing on OS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course your solution is possible. You can create the four mentioned repositories and use svn::external property to get the common repository whenever each platform-specific repo is being checked out.  But, as far as you are developing a single web application for different platforms, separating the repositories is not a good practice. Doing this way, tagging your whole product (e.g. all platform-specific parts) is a hard work.

Comment: Keep your whole stuff in the same repo, but separate the folders for common and platform-specific materials. For each platform-specific folder, define a svn::externals property to the get the common directory as well. You may restrict the access to platform-specific folders by setting access right. Doing this way, each developer will check out its platform-specific code. Then the common directory will be automatically copied in its working folder.